# Finding the determinant of the 5x5 matrix but can't put it in lower triangular form

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How to find the determinant of this 5x5 matrix? I can't put it in Lower or Upper Triangular form so I'm confused. I dont really know how to use laplace expansion

$\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\-3&0&-2&0&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&-1&2&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I tried to get all 0's in the diagonal and i then deleted row 1 column  1 so that i now have a 4x4 matrix so i did

$R_2 = R_1 + R_2$ then I did $R_4 = R_2 - R_4$ then I got $3 \begin{bmatrix}0&-2&3&0\\-1&0&0&-3\\0&-2&0&-3\\-1&2&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ = $3(-1)(-2)(2)(-1) + 3(-2)(3)(-3)(-3) = -498 $ but i did $R_2 - R_4$ so i divided by a factor of -1 and got $\det(A) = -498/-1 = 498$ which was still incorrect

Comment: Just do elementary row operations, using your knowledge of how each one changes the value of the determinant.

Comment: Your matrix is somewhat sparse, why not just calculate the determinant by definition?

Comment: @Bye_World You're implying that i put it in either Lower Triang or Upper Triang form correct?

Comment: @Aweygan Elaborate

Comment: @Shammy Basically yes.  I'm saying put it in REF form (keeping track of how the determinant changes) -- which just happens to be a triangular matrix.

Comment: @Shammy A cofactor expansion.

Comment: @Aweygan Yea idk what you;re talking about

Comment: @Bye_World I tried to get it in LTF but I can't because I get left with a number that I can't get rid of!

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\0&0&-2&3&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&-1&2&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @shammy Are you still interested in applying laplace expansion ?

Comment: wouldnt hurt to see it @callculus

Comment: ill reward with a upvote but i gave byeworld the answer check mark@callculus

Comment: Remember that swapping rows (which changes the sign of the determinant) is one of the tools in your kit. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1502099/265466) for another example of a $5\times 5$ determinant.

Comment: @Shammy I posted an answer. If you have any question feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ERO Method:**

$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\-3&0&-2&0&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&-1&2&0&0\end{vmatrix} &=\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\0&0&-2&3&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&-1&2&0&0\end{vmatrix} \tag{$R_2\to R_2+R_1$}\\ &=\color{red}{-}\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&-2&3&0\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&-1&2&0&0\end{vmatrix} \tag{$R_3\leftrightarrow R_2$} \\ &=-\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&-2&3&0\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&0&2&0&3\end{vmatrix} \tag{$R_5\to R_5-R_2$} \\ &=-\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&-2&3&0\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&0&0&3&3\end{vmatrix} \tag{$R_5\to R_5+R_3$} \\ &=-\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&-2&3&0\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&0&0&0&0\end{vmatrix} \tag{$R_5\to R_5-R_4$} \\ &=0\end{align}$$

---

**Laplace Expansion Method:**

Each row and column has $2$ entries so I don't see any strategic way to choose where to expand this.  So I'll just go across the first row first:
$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}3&0&0&3&0\\-3&0&-2&0&0\\0&-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&0&3&3\\0&-1&2&0&0\end{vmatrix} &= 3\begin{vmatrix}0&-2&0&0\\-1&0&0&-3\\0&0&3&3\\-1&2&0&0\end{vmatrix} + -3\begin{vmatrix}-3&0&-2&0\\0&-1&0&-3\\0&0&0&3\\0&-1&2&0\end{vmatrix}\end{align}$$

Now I'll expand along the first row of the first and first column of the second:

$$=3\left[-(-2)\begin{vmatrix}-1 & 0 & -3 \\ 0 & 3 & 3 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{vmatrix}\right]+-3\left[-3\begin{vmatrix}-1 & 0 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \\ -1 & 2 & 0\end{vmatrix}\right]$$

From here expand along the third and second rows and evaluate the $2\times 2$ determinant in the normal way to get $$=6[-(0--9)]+9[-3(-2-0)] = 0$$

---

**Exterior Product Method:**

$$\begin{align}&(3e_1-3e_2)\wedge(-e_3-e_5)\wedge(-2e_2+2e_5)\wedge(3e_1+3e_4)\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4) \\ &= \big[3e_1\wedge(-e_3-e_5)\wedge(-2e_2+2e_5)\wedge(3e_1+3e_4)\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4)\big] \\ &\quad -\big[3e_2\wedge(-e_3-e_5)\wedge(-2e_2+2e_5)\wedge(3e_1+3e_4)\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4)\big] \\ &= \big[3e_1\wedge(-e_3-e_5)\wedge(-2e_2+2e_5)\wedge(3e_4)\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4)\big] \\&\quad -\big[3e_2\wedge(-e_3-e_5)\wedge(2e_5)\wedge(3e_1+3e_4)\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4)\big] \\ &= -9\big[e_1\wedge e_3\wedge(-2e_2+2e_5)\wedge e_4\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4)\big] \\ &\quad -9\big[e_1\wedge e_5\wedge(-2e_2+2e_5)\wedge e_4\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4)\big] \\ &\quad +6\big[e_2\wedge e_3\wedge e_5\wedge(3e_1+3e_4)\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4)\big]\\ &\quad +6\big[e_1\wedge e_5\wedge e_5\wedge(3e_1+3e_4)\wedge (-3e_3+3e_4)\big] \\ &= -9\big[0\big]-9\big[e_1\wedge e_5\wedge(-2e_2)\wedge e_4\wedge (-3e_3)\big] +6\big[e_2\wedge e_3\wedge e_5\wedge(3e_1+3e_4)\wedge (3e_4)\big]+6\big[0\big] \\ &= (-9\cdot 6)I+(6\cdot9)I \\ &=0I\end{align}$$

---

**Happen-to-Notice-Linear-Dependence Method:**

Notice that $R_1 = -R_2+R_3+R_4-R_5$.  So because the rows are not linearly independent, the determinant must be $0$.

Comment: god i can never figure out how u guys see things so fast i can never see. i never ever would of thought to swap them -_-

Comment: If you have a question about any of the above methods, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

**laplace expansion**

I go on at your intermediate result.

$3\begin{bmatrix}0&\color{red}{-2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{0}\\ \color{blue}{-1}&0&0&-3\\ 0&\color{red}{-2}&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{-3}\\ \color{green}{-1}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{0}\end{bmatrix}$

$\color{blue}{-1}$ is positioned in the second row and and in the first column. Thus $(-1)*(-1)^{2+1}=1$ The correspoonding submatrix consist the red numbers.

Similar calculation for the green $\color{green}{-1}$. The sign is positive as well, because $(-1)*(-1)^{4+1}=1$

Thus $det \ A= 3\cdot 1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\color{red}{-2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{0}\\ \color{red}{-2}&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{-3}\\ \color{red}{2}&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{0}\end{bmatrix}+3\cdot 1\cdot \begin{bmatrix}-2&3&0\\ 0&0&-3\\ -2&0&-3\end{bmatrix}$

$=3\cdot 1\cdot (0-18+0-0-0-0)+3\cdot 1\cdot (0+18+0-0-0-0)=-54+54=0$